# Airflow scheduler gets stuck

Tags: python-3.6, airflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux, airflow-scheduler

I have setup airflow on Windows 10 WSL with Python 3.6.8. I started the scheduler of airflow using `airflow scheduler` command but it got following error :

```
[2020-04-28 19:24:06,500] {base_job.py:205} ERROR - SchedulerJob heartbeat got an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 755, in _commit_impl
    self.engine.dialect.do_commit(self.connection)
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 543, in do_commit
    dbapi_connection.commit()
sqlite3.OperationalError: disk I/O error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/base_job.py", line 173, in heartbeat
    previous_heartbeat = self.latest_heartbeat
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 88, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 45, in create_session
    session.commit()
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1036, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 507, in commit
    t[1].commit()
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1736, in commit
    self._do_commit()
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1767, in _do_commit
    self.connection._commit_impl()
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 757, in _commit_impl
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(e, None, None, None, None)
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1482, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 755, in _commit_impl
    self.engine.dialect.do_commit(self.connection)
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 543, in do_commit
    dbapi_connection.commit()
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) disk I/O error
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

What is the reason for this failing? What can be the solution to resolve this as my airflow scheduler is running well since last 10 days?

Comment: Did you run the `airflow initdb` command to initialise the database? You need to edit the airflow.cfg to point to your database and then run that command to get going. See here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/initialize-database.html

Comment: @SimonD : I did execute the airflow initdb command to initialise the database but it is giving the same error